# Multiple dropdown menus using same JS code

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I have a simple drop-down menu using JavaScript.

```
<div id="show-nav" class="dropdown">

    <div id="dropdown" onClick="myFunction()">Menu Name</div>

          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

                <a href="#option1">Option 1</a>
                <a href="#option2">Option 2</a>
                <a href="#option3">Option 3</a>

          </div>

       </div>
```

And the JS:

```
<script>

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('#dropdown')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}

</script>
```

I have multiple copies of the same menu in several adjacent divs. With this code, the menu works in the first element, but if I try to toggle it in the second, it only drops down in the first. How can I make this work for several menus on a single page?

Comment: `html` code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To the `myFunction` pass `this`. That is:

```
 <div id="dropdown" onClick="myFunction(this)">Menu Name</div>
```

Write a JavaScript function like below:

```
function myFunction(a) {
  a.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

No need of that much of JavaScript: keep as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need two changes on your code :

- Make all buttons' `onClick` attributes same. (I guess it is "myFunction();")
- Change your handler to process the button which is actually clicked.

This is possible with event.target :

```
function myFunction(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: All the onClick attributes at the moment are like this:

    <div id="dropdown" onClick="myFunction()">Menu name</div>

Are you saying I replace the first bit of code the above? Or that I need to add that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this without written any long javascript code.

use this

```html
<div id="show-nav" class="dropbtn">

    <div id="dropdown" onClick="myFunction(this)">Menu Name</div>

          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

                <a href="#option1">Option 1</a>
                <a href="#option2">Option 2</a>
                <a href="#option3">Option 3</a>

          </div>

       </div>

       <div id="show-nav" class="dropbtn" style="margin-left:300px; margin-top:-16px;">

    <div id="dropdown" onClick="myFunction(this)">Menu Name</div>

          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

                <a href="#option1">Option 1</a>
                <a href="#option2">Option 2</a>
                <a href="#option3">Option 3</a>

          </div>

       </div>
```

```js
function myFunction(a) {
  a.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
position: absolute;
right:5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {

  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;


  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;

  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}




.show {
  display: block;
}
```